# Mini Scheme interpreter

Tags: java, parsing, scheme, interpreter, antlr

Right now, I'm working on an interpreter for a subset of the Scheme programming language. It supports lambdas, `let/let*/letrec`, procedures, combinations, definitions, conditionals, do-iteration, and closures. I'm going for a "everything that can be simplified, should be simplified" paradigm to make interpreting the language easier. For example, in the parser, all syntactic sugar forms (e.g., `let`, `let*`, and procedures) are converted to their lambda equivalents. The same is true for `if` (it is converted to `cond`).

I'd like to get feedback on the interpreter itself. I think it's fairly compact and detailed right now, but any optimizations or improvements are greatly appreciated. For combinations (or applications), there's another class `BuiltinOperator` which simply checks to see if the operator is a primitive (e.g., `cons`, `+`, `*`, etc.).

For reference, I've written this in Java with the ANTLR parser generator. I've decided to also include the class that generates the abstract syntax tree for the interpreter (i.e., the parse tree listener) with the hopes that someone can provide feedback.

**`MiniSchemeInterpreter.java`** *Warning: around 600 LOC*

```
/******************************************************************************
 *  File: MiniSchemeInterpreter.java
 *
 *  Author: Me
 *
 *  Last Updated: 01/29/2022
 *
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

public class MiniSchemeInterpreter {

    /**
     * MSSyntaxTree associated with this interpreter.
     */
    private MSSyntaxTree tree;

    public MiniSchemeInterpreter(final MSSyntaxTree interpreterTree) {
        this.tree = interpreterTree;
    }

    public MiniSchemeInterpreter() {
        this(null);
    }

    public void execute() {
        Environment globals = new Environment(null);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tree.getChildrenSize(); i++) {
            MSSyntaxTree currNode = this.tree.getChild(i);
            try {
                LValue result = this.interpretTree(currNode, globals);
                if (result != null) { System.out.println(result); }
            } catch (MSSemanticException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private LValue interpretTree(final MSSyntaxTree tree, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        switch (tree.getNodeType()) {
            case NUMBER: return this.interpretNumber((MSNumberNode) tree);
            case BOOLEAN: return this.interpretBoolean((MSBooleanNode) tree);
            case CHARACTER: return this.interpretCharacter((MSCharacterNode) tree);
            case STRING: return this.interpretString((MSStringNode) tree);
            case SYMBOL: return this.interpretSymbol((MSSymbolNode) tree);
            case QUASISYMBOL: return this.interpretQuasiSymbol((MSQuasiSymbolNode) tree, env);
            case VARIABLE: return this.interpretVariable((MSVariableNode) tree, env);
            case SEQUENCE: return this.interpretSequence((MSSequenceNode) tree, env);
            case DECLARATION: return this.interpretDeclaration((MSDeclarationNode) tree, env);
            case SET: return this.interpretSet((MSSetNode) tree, env);
            case SETCAR: return this.interpretSetCar((MSSetNode) tree, env);
            case SETCDR: return this.interpretSetCdr((MSSetNode) tree, env);
            case SETVECTOR: return this.interpretSetVector((MSSetNode) tree, env);
            case COND: return this.interpretCond((MSCondNode) tree, env);
            case LETREC: return this.interpretLetRec((MSLetRecNode) tree, env);
            case LAMBDA: return this.interpretLambda((MSLambdaNode) tree, env);
            case DO: return this.interpretDo((MSDoNode) tree, env);
            case EVAL: return this.interpretEval((MSEvalNode) tree, env);
            case APPLY: return this.interpretApply((MSApplyNode) tree, env);
            case APPLICATION: return this.interpretApplication((MSApplicationNode) tree, env);
            default:
                throw new MSInterpreterException("Unsupported node type " + tree.getNodeType());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts a MSNumberNode AST into an LValue.
     *  
     * @param numberNode AST
     * 
     * @return LValue with number.
     */
    private LValue interpretNumber(final MSNumberNode numberNode) {
        return new LValue(numberNode);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a MSBooleanNode AST into an LValue.
     * 
     * @param booleanNode AST
     * 
     * @return LValue with boolean.
     */
    private LValue interpretBoolean(final MSBooleanNode booleanNode) {
        return new LValue(booleanNode);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a MSStringNode AST into an LValue.
     * 
     * @param stringNode AST
     * 
     * @return LValue with string.
     */
    private LValue interpretString(final MSStringNode stringNode) {
        return new LValue(stringNode);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a MSCharacterNode AST into an LValue.
     * 
     * @param characterNode AST
     * 
     * @return LValue with character.
     */
    private LValue interpretCharacter(final MSCharacterNode characterNode) { return new LValue(characterNode); }

    /**
     * Converts a MSSymbolNode AST into an LValue.
     * 
     * @param symbolNode AST
     * 
     * @return LValue with symbol.
     */
    private LValue interpretSymbol(final MSSymbolNode symbolNode) { return new LValue(symbolNode.getValue()); }

    /**
     * Interprets a quasi-symbol. A quasi-symbol is just a quoted expression that has the potential to have
     * "unquote" sections. An unquoted section is a section that should get evaluated when interpreting the
     * parent expression.
     *
     * Example: `(1 2 ,(+ 3 4) 5) evaluates to (1 2 7 5) because the , indicates that the next expression
     *          is to be evaluated.
     *
     * List splicing is also supported. List splicing allows elements of a sublist to be added to the current
     * list.
     *
     * Example: `(1 2 ,@(list 3 4 5) 6) evaluates to (1 2 3 4 5 6) because the list expands outward. If we
     *          did not have the @ operator, it would evaluate to (1 2 (3 4 5) 6).
     *
     * @param quasiSymbolNode AST.
     * @param env Environment to evaluate this quasi-symbol in.
     * @return LValue containing the list constructed from this quasi quote.
     */
    private LValue interpretQuasiSymbol(final MSQuasiSymbolNode quasiSymbolNode, final Environment env) {
        // If it's a quasi-list, we need to create a new list and interpret each element that is unquoted.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> quasiNodes = quasiSymbolNode.getSymbolList();
        MSListNode currList = null;
        for (int i = quasiNodes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            MSSyntaxTree quasi = quasiNodes.get(i);
            // If it's not a symbol, we just need to evaluate it.
            if (!quasi.isSymbol()) { quasi = LValue.getAst(this.interpretTree(quasi, env)); }
            else {
                MSSymbolNode symbol = (MSSymbolNode) quasi;
                // If it's a "quasi-at-symbol", then we need to store its elements *inside* the list.
                if (symbol.isQuasiAtSymbol()) {
                    MSSyntaxTree symbolValue = LValue.getAst(this.interpretTree(symbol.getValue(), env));
                    if (!symbolValue.isList()) {
                        throw new MSArgumentMismatchException(",@", "list/cons pair", symbolValue.getStringNodeType());
                    }
                    // Extract each element from the symbol list and append it to the curr list.
                    ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> symbolList = ((MSListNode) symbolValue).getListAsArrayList();
                    for (int j = symbolList.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        MSSyntaxTree rhsElement = symbolList.get(j);
                        currList = new MSListNode(rhsElement, currList);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
            currList = new MSListNode(quasi, currList);
        }
        return new LValue(Optional.ofNullable(currList).orElse(MSListNode.EMPTY_LIST), env);
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a variable in the provided environment. If it is not found in the passed environment or its
     * parent and it's not an operator, an error is displayed.
     * 
     * @param variableNode AST
     * @param env Environment to look variable up in
     * 
     * @return LValue of variable data in environment. If it is a builtin operator, we just return the variableNode.
     * 
     * @throws MSSemanticException if variableNode is not found in env and it's not builtin.
     */
    private LValue interpretVariable(final MSVariableNode variableNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue variableData = env.lookup(variableNode.getIdentifier());
        if (variableData != null) { return variableData; }
        else if (BuiltinOperator.isBuiltinOperator(variableNode)) { return new LValue(variableNode, env); }
        else { throw new MSUndefinedSymbolException(variableNode.getStringRep()); }
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a declaration. We first evaluate the right-hand side, then bind it to the passed environment.
     * 
     * @param declarationNode AST.
     * @param env Environment to store declaration in.
     * 
     * @return null (declarations do not return any values).
     * 
     * @throws MSSemanticException if an exception is thrown when interpreting the rhs.
     */
    private LValue interpretDeclaration(final MSDeclarationNode declarationNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue rExpr = this.interpretTree(declarationNode.getExpression(), env);
        env.bind(declarationNode.getVariable().getStringRep(), rExpr);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Interprets an eval. An eval simply takes in an expression, quoted or unquoted, and attempts to
     * evaluate it. If it is a variable, this is resolved to its value in the environment. From there,
     * if it is a symbol, we remove the quote. Then, there are two choices:
     *
     * 1. If the expression is not a list, we just pass down the unquoted symbol.
     * 2. Otherwise, we create a MSApplyNode with the CAR as the operator and CDR as operand.
     *
     * @param evalNode AST.
     * @param env current environment to evaluate inside.
     *
     * @return LValue of interpreting either the unquoted expression or the apply, whichever is applicable.
     */
    private LValue interpretEval(final MSEvalNode evalNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        // First, we want to resolve the expr argument. If it's a variable, retrieve it.
        MSSyntaxTree expression = evalNode.getExpression();
        if (expression.isVariable()) { expression = LValue.getAst(this.interpretTree(expression, env)); }
        // Now, if it's a symbol, resolve that (i.e., get its value).
        if (expression.isSymbol()) { expression = ((MSSymbolNode) expression).getValue(); }
        // If it's a list, create an "apply" out of it.
        if (!expression.isList()) { return this.interpretTree(expression, env); }
        MSListNode listNode = (MSListNode) expression;
        return this.interpretTree(new MSApplyNode(listNode.getCar(), listNode.getCdr()), env);
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a sequence of expressions.
     *
     * @param sequence AST
     * @param env Environment to interpret the sequence of expressions in.
     *
     * @return LValue of last expression evaluated in the sequence.
     *
     * @throws MSSemanticException if an exception is thrown when interpreting the sequence.
     */
    private LValue interpretSequence(final MSSequenceNode sequence, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue returnValue = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.getChildrenSize(); i++) {
            returnValue = this.interpretTree(sequence.getChild(i), env);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a conditional (cond or if). Each conditional is evaluated from left-to-right, and if
     * this conditional is true, we evaluate its corresponding consequent expression. If there is an
     * else expression and none of the cond expressions are true, it is evaluated last.
     *
     * @param condNode AST of either a COND or an IF.
     * @param env Environment to evaluate the conditionals in.
     *
     * @return LValue of consequent expression evaluated.
     *
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if the cond's predicate is not a predicate (i.e., does not reduce to boolean).
     * @throws MSSemanticException if the conditional does not have an else but requires one (all cases fall through).
     */
    private LValue interpretCond(final MSCondNode condNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condPredicateList = condNode.getPredicateList();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condConsequentList = condNode.getConsequentList();

        for (int i = 0; i < condPredicateList.size(); i++) {
            MSSyntaxTree currPredicate = condPredicateList.get(i);
            LValue currPredicateLValue = this.interpretTree(currPredicate, env);
            MSSyntaxTree predicateAst = LValue.getAst(currPredicateLValue);
            if (!predicateAst.isBoolean()) {
                throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("cond", "predicate/true/false", predicateAst.getStringNodeType());
            } else if (currPredicateLValue.getBooleanValue()) {
                return this.interpretTree(condConsequentList.get(i), env);
            }
        }

        if (condNode.hasElse()) { return this.interpretTree(condConsequentList.get(condConsequentList.size() - 1), env); }
        throw new MSSemanticException("cannot evaluate an undefined expression");
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a DO iterative loop. A do loop in Scheme has a declaration section, "variable steps",
     * a test, a list of "true" expressions, and then the body.
     *
     * Do sets up the variable bindings in a new local environment. It then evaluates the do test, and
     * if it is true, we evaluate the "do true" expressions. Otherwise, we evaluate the body of the
     * do loop. Finally, the "variable steps" (i.e., a list of SETs) are processed.
     *
     * @param doNode AST.
     * @param env parent environment of the do node.
     *
     * @return LValue of the last "true" expression evaluated.
     *
     * @throws MSSemanticException if the "test" is not boolean expression, or a sub-evaluation throws
     *         an exception.
     */
    private LValue interpretDo(final MSDoNode doNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        // First, set up the declarations and evaluate their expressions.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> doFormals = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<LValue> evalDoArguments = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MSSyntaxTree formal : doNode.getDoDeclarations()) {
            MSDeclarationNode declaration = (MSDeclarationNode) formal;
            doFormals.add(declaration.getVariable());
            evalDoArguments.add(this.interpretTree(declaration.getExpression(), env));
        }

        // Then, create the local environment used for the do.
        Environment doEnv = env.createChildEnvironment(doFormals, evalDoArguments);
        while (true) {
            // Evaluate the test expression. If true, evaluate the true args and return the LValue of the last.
            LValue testLVal = this.interpretTree(doNode.getDoTest(), doEnv);
            MSSyntaxTree testAst = LValue.getAst(testLVal);
            if (!testAst.isBoolean()) {
                throw new MSSemanticException("do test expected predicate/true/false but got " + testAst.getStringNodeType());
            } else {
                if (testLVal.getBooleanValue()) {
                    LValue trueLVal = null;
                    for (MSSyntaxTree trueExpr : doNode.getDoTrueExpressions()) {
                        trueLVal = this.interpretTree(trueExpr, doEnv);
                    }
                    return trueLVal;
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, evaluate the body then do the step. LValues are irrelevant.
                    LValue body = this.interpretTree(doNode.getDoBody(), doEnv);
                    if (body != null) { System.out.println(body); }
                    for (MSSyntaxTree setExpr : doNode.getDoSetExpressions()) {
                        LValue setLVal = this.interpretTree(setExpr, doEnv);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates a letrec expression. A letrec is a recursive let procedure (i.e., allows the programmer to
     * call a lambda procedure defined in the let declarations inside the body of the let. This probably isn't
     * the most useful thing in the world, but it's here because it can't be converted into a lambda.
     *
     * The bindings are created inside an environment with env as the parent. This environment must be constructed
     * because any lambdas in the bindings must have their env set as the new environment or they won't be
     * recognized.
     *
     * @param letRecNode AST.
     * @param env parent Environment to create the child Environment for the let from.
     * @return LValue of evaluated let body.
     */
    private LValue interpretLetRec(final MSLetRecNode letRecNode, final Environment env) {
        ArrayList<LValue> expressionList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Create the new environment so we can bind our let declarations in it.
        Environment newEnv = new Environment(env);
        for (MSSyntaxTree ast : letRecNode.getDeclarationList()) {
            MSDeclarationNode decl = (MSDeclarationNode) ast;
            expressionList.add(new LValue(decl.getExpression(), newEnv));
        }

        newEnv.createBindings(letRecNode.getVariableList(), expressionList);
        return this.interpretTree(letRecNode.getBody(), newEnv);
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a lambda AST.
     *
     * @param lambdaNode AST
     * @param env Environment to evaluate the lambda in.
     *
     * @return LValue wrapping the lambda and its current environment.
     */
    private LValue interpretLambda(final MSLambdaNode lambdaNode, final Environment env) {
        return new LValue(lambdaNode, env);
    }

    /**
     * Interprets an "apply" node. Apply works very similarly to "application" nodes with the exception
     * that apply takes an operator and a list rather than separate arguments. The procedure is collectively
     * applied to (as the name suggests!) each element of the list. To make things easier, after checking
     * the node, we create a MSApplicationNode since it does all the heavy lifting.
     *
     * @param applyNode AST.
     * @param env current environment to evaluate ApplyNode in.
     *
     * @return LValue of creating and interpreting the new MSApplicationNode.
     *
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if we try to pass a non list/cons pair to apply.
     */
    private LValue interpretApply(final MSApplyNode applyNode, final Environment env) throws MSArgumentMismatchException {
        // First, we want to resolve the apply node's argument.
        MSSyntaxTree argument = applyNode.getArgumentList();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> applyArguments = new ArrayList<>();
        if (argument.isVariable()) { argument = LValue.getAst(this.interpretTree(argument, env)); }
        // Now check to make sure it's a symbol or list.
        if (argument.isSymbol()) { argument = ((MSSymbolNode) argument).getValue(); }
        // Finally, check to make sure it's a list.
        if (!argument.isList()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("apply", 1, "list/cons pair", argument.getStringNodeType()); }

        MSListNode curr = (MSListNode) argument;
        while (true) {
            if (curr.isEmptyList()) { break; }
            else {
                applyArguments.add(curr.getCar());
                curr = (MSListNode) curr.getCdr();
            }
        }

        MSSyntaxTree procedure = applyNode.getProcedure();
        return this.interpretTree(new MSApplicationNode(procedure, applyArguments), env);
    }

    /**
     * Interprets an application node. An application is, effectively the "apply" function in many
     * Scheme interpreters. It takes the node (which contains the operator and operands/arguments,
     * as well as an environment to evaluate the arguments in.
     * 
     * Each argument is evaluated in env prior to application. A new environment E' is constructed 
     * with these arguments bound to E'. The body is then evaluated in E'.
     * 
     * @param applicationNode AST with operand and arguments. 
     * @param env Environment to evaluate arguments in, and to create child env.
     * 
     * @return LValue of interpreted application.
     */
    private LValue interpretApplication(final MSApplicationNode applicationNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        // First, interpret all the children.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> rhsArguments = applicationNode.getArguments();
        ArrayList<LValue> evaluatedArguments = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MSSyntaxTree rhsArg : rhsArguments) {
            LValue lhs = this.interpretTree(rhsArg, env);
            evaluatedArguments.add(lhs);
        }

        // Now, check to see if the left-hand side (the caller) is a primitive.
        LValue lhsLValue = this.interpretTree(applicationNode.getExpression(), env);
        MSSyntaxTree expressionLVal = LValue.getAst(lhsLValue);
        if (BuiltinOperator.isBuiltinOperator(expressionLVal)) { return BuiltinOperator.interpretBuiltinOperator(expressionLVal, evaluatedArguments, env); }
        else {
            // If we're trying to call on a non-lambda, throw an exception.
            if (!expressionLVal.isLambda()) { throw new MSSemanticException("cannot call " + expressionLVal.getStringRep()); }

            // Otherwise, create the bindings and interpret the body.
            MSLambdaNode lambdaNode = (MSLambdaNode) expressionLVal;
            Environment lambdaEnvironment = lhsLValue.getEnvironment();
            ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> lambdaParameters = lambdaNode.getLambdaParameters();
            MSSyntaxTree lambdaBody = lambdaNode.getLambdaBody();

            // Before we bind, check arity.
            if (lambdaParameters.size() != evaluatedArguments.size()) {
                throw new MSArgumentMismatchException(lambdaParameters.size(), evaluatedArguments.size());
            }

            Environment e1 = lambdaEnvironment.createChildEnvironment(lambdaParameters, evaluatedArguments);
            return this.interpretTree(lambdaBody, e1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a SET! Scheme procedure. SET! is only used for redefining a variable as a new expression.
     * With this in mind, the left-hand side can only be a variable - not something that reduces to an 
     * lvalue. The set expression is evaluated in the current environment, which it is then bound to. We 
     * bind the value at every environment that is a parent of the current env.
     * 
     * @param setNode AST with set assignee and expression to assign.
     * @param env current Environment.
     * 
     * @return null, because set expressions never return a value.
     * 
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if the lhs expression is not a variable.
     * @throws MSUndefinedSymbolException if either the expression throws an exception while evaluating, or the 
     *                                    variable is not bound in the environment or its parent.
     */
    private LValue interpretSet(final MSSetNode setNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        MSSyntaxTree assignee = setNode.getChild(0);
        LValue evaluatedExpression = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(1), env);
        if (!assignee.isVariable()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("set!", 0, "variable", assignee.getStringNodeType()); }
        String id = ((MSVariableNode) assignee).getIdentifier();
        Environment curr = env;
        boolean found = false;
        while (curr != null) {
            LValue lookupSymbol = curr.lookup(id);
            if (lookupSymbol != null) { found = true; curr.bind(id, evaluatedExpression); }
            curr = curr.getParent();
        }
        
        if (!found) { throw new MSUndefinedSymbolException(id); }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a set-car! expression. set-car! takes an lvalue that is equivalent to a list or cons pair,
     * then assigns its CAR as the expression in the SetNode AST.
     * 
     * @param setNode AST passed as a reference. The list/cons pair, itself, is rebound, rather than the symbol
     *                in its environment.
     * @param env current Environment.
     * 
     * @return null, because set expressions never return a value.
     * 
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if the first argument is not a list or cons pair.
     */
    private LValue interpretSetCar(final MSSetNode setNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue evaluatedAssignee = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(0), env);
        LValue evaluatedExpression = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(1), env);

        MSSyntaxTree assigneeAst = LValue.getAst(evaluatedAssignee);
        if (!assigneeAst.isList()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("set-car!", 0, "list/cons pair", assigneeAst.getStringNodeType()); }
        ((MSListNode) assigneeAst).setCar(LValue.getAst(evaluatedExpression));
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a set-cdr! expression. set-cdr! takes an lvalue that is equivalent to a list or cons pair,
     * then assigns its CDR as the expression in the SetNode AST.
     * 
     * @param setNode AST passed as a reference. The list/cons pair, itself, is rebound, rather than the symbol
     *                in its environment.
     * @param env current Environment.
     * 
     * @return null, because set expressions never return a value.
     * 
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if the first argument is not a list or cons pair.
     */
    private LValue interpretSetCdr(final MSSetNode setNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue evaluatedAssignee = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(0), env);
        LValue evaluatedExpression = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(1), env);

        MSSyntaxTree assigneeAst = LValue.getAst(evaluatedAssignee);
        if (!assigneeAst.isList()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("set-cdr!", 0, "list/cons pair", assigneeAst.getStringNodeType()); }
        ((MSListNode) assigneeAst).setCdr(LValue.getAst(evaluatedExpression));
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Interprets a vector-set! expression. vector-set! takes an lvalue that is equivalent to a vector,
     * then assigns the provided index to the evaluated expression.
     * 
     * @param setNode AST passed as a reference. The vector, itself, is rebound, rather than the symbol
     *                in its environment.
     * @param env current Environment.
     * 
     * @return null, because set expressions never return a value.
     * 
     * @throws MSArgumentMismatchException if the first argument is not a list or cons pair.
     *                                     It also throws an exception when vectorIdx is not a number.
     */
    private LValue interpretSetVector(final MSSetNode setNode, final Environment env) throws MSSemanticException {
        LValue evaluatedAssignee = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(0), env);
        LValue vectorIdx = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(1), env);
        LValue evaluatedExpression = this.interpretTree(setNode.getChild(2), env);
        MSSyntaxTree assigneeAst = LValue.getAst(evaluatedAssignee);
        MSSyntaxTree vectorIdxAst = LValue.getAst(vectorIdx);
        if (!assigneeAst.isVector()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("vector-set!", 0, "vector", assigneeAst.getStringNodeType()); }
        else if (!LValue.getAst(vectorIdx).isNumber()) { throw new MSArgumentMismatchException("vector-set!", 1, "number", vectorIdxAst.getStringNodeType()); }
        ((MSVectorNode) assigneeAst).setChild(vectorIdx.getNumberValue().intValue(), LValue.getAst(evaluatedExpression));
        return null;
    }

    public void setInterpreterTree(final MSSyntaxTree interpreterTree) {
        this.tree = interpreterTree;
    }
}
```

**`MiniSchemeListener.java`** *Warning: around 400 LoC*

```
/******************************************************************************
 *  File: MSListener.java
 *
 *  Author: Me
 *
 *  Last Updated: 01/25/2022
 *
 *
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeProperty;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

public class MSListener extends MiniSchemeBaseListener {

    /**
     * ParseTreeProperty map of parser rules being constructed overtime.
     */
    private final ParseTreeProperty<MSSyntaxTree> map;

    /**
     * Root of the AST being constructed.
     */
    private final MSSyntaxTree root;

    public MSListener() {
        this.root = new MSSyntaxTree();
        this.map = new ParseTreeProperty<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void exitMiniScheme(final MiniSchemeParser.MiniSchemeContext ctx) {
        super.exitMiniScheme(ctx);
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.children.size(); i++) {
            if (ctx.getChild(i) != null) {
                this.root.addChild(this.map.get(ctx.getChild(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitDecl(final MiniSchemeParser.DeclContext ctx) {
        super.exitDecl(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, this.map.get(ctx.getChild(0)));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitExpr(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, this.map.get(ctx.getChild(0)));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitBeginExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.BeginExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitBeginExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> expressions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ParseTree pt : ctx.expr()) {
            expressions.add(this.map.get(pt));
        }
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSSequenceNode(expressions));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitVariableDeclaration(final MiniSchemeParser.VariableDeclarationContext ctx) {
        super.exitVariableDeclaration(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSDeclarationNode(this.map.get(ctx.variable()), this.map.get(ctx.expr())));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitProcedureDeclaration(final MiniSchemeParser.ProcedureDeclarationContext ctx) {
        super.exitProcedureDeclaration(ctx);
        MSSyntaxTree procedureName = this.map.get(ctx.variable());
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> procedureParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ctx.procedureParameters().expr() != null) {
            for (ParseTree pt : ctx.procedureParameters().expr()) {
                procedureParameters.add(this.map.get(pt));
            }
        }

        MSSyntaxTree procedureBody = this.map.get(ctx.expr());
        MSLambdaNode procedureLambda = new MSLambdaNode(procedureParameters, procedureBody);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSDeclarationNode(procedureName, procedureLambda));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitEvalExpr(MiniSchemeParser.EvalExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitEvalExpr(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSEvalNode(this.map.get(ctx.expr())));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitApplyExpr(MiniSchemeParser.ApplyExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitApplyExpr(ctx);
        MSSyntaxTree procedure = this.map.get(ctx.expr(0));
        MSSyntaxTree argumentList = this.map.get(ctx.expr(1));
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSApplyNode(procedure, argumentList));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitApplicationExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.ApplicationExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitApplicationExpr(ctx);
        MSSyntaxTree lhsExpression = this.map.get(ctx.expr());
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ctx.expr() != null) {
            for (ParseTree pt : ctx.applicationArgs().expr()) {
                arguments.add(this.map.get(pt));
            }
        }

        this.map.put(ctx, new MSApplicationNode(lhsExpression, arguments));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitDoExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.DoExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitDoExpr(ctx);
        // First, collect the variable declarations and set expressions.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> doDeclarations = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> doSetExpressions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.doDecl().size(); i++) {
            MSSyntaxTree varNode = this.map.get(ctx.doDecl().get(i).variable());
            MSSyntaxTree expressionNode = this.map.get(ctx.doDecl().get(i).expr(0));
            doDeclarations.add(new MSDeclarationNode(varNode, expressionNode));
            // Check to see if there's a second expression, indicating we need a SET.
            if (ctx.doDecl().get(i).expr(1) != null) {
                MSSyntaxTree setExpression = this.map.get(ctx.doDecl().get(i).expr(1));
                ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> setData = new ArrayList<>();
                setData.add(varNode);
                setData.add(setExpression);
                doSetExpressions.add(new MSSetNode(MiniSchemeParser.SET, setData));
            }
        }

        // Now, retrieve the test condition and what to do when it is true.
        MSSyntaxTree doTestExpression = this.map.get(ctx.doTest().expr());
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> doTrueExpressions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.doTrueExpr().size(); i++) {
            doTrueExpressions.add(this.map.get(ctx.doTrueExpr().get(i).expr()));
        }

        // Finally, retrieve the body.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> doBodyList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.doBody().expr().size(); i++) {
            doBodyList.add(this.map.get(ctx.doBody().expr().get(i)));
        }

        MSSequenceNode doBody = new MSSequenceNode(doBodyList);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSDoNode(doDeclarations, doSetExpressions, doTestExpression, doTrueExpressions, doBody));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitLetExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.LetExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitLetExpr(ctx);
        // Convert the let into a lambda as an application.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> letVariables = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> letBindings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.letParameters().size(); i++) {
            letVariables.add(this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(0)));
            letBindings.add(this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(1)));
        }
        MSSyntaxTree letBody = this.map.get(ctx.expr());
        MSLambdaNode lambdaNode = new MSLambdaNode(letVariables, letBody);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSApplicationNode(lambdaNode, letBindings));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitLetStarExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.LetStarExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitLetStarExpr(ctx);
        MSApplicationNode rootApplication = null;
        for (int i = ctx.letParameters().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Retrieve the variable and its data. Create a lambda node from
            // them and attach it as the body of the next outer lambda.
            ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> letArgument = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> letParameter = new ArrayList<>();
            letParameter.add(this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(0)));
            letArgument.add(this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(1)));
            // If we're on the first expression, we need to create the lambda with the body as the expr.
            MSLambdaNode lambdaNode;
            if (i == ctx.letParameters().size() - 1) { lambdaNode = new MSLambdaNode(letParameter, this.map.get(ctx.expr())); }
            else { lambdaNode = new MSLambdaNode(letParameter, rootApplication); }
            rootApplication = new MSApplicationNode(lambdaNode, letArgument);
        }

        this.map.put(ctx, rootApplication);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitLetRecExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.LetRecExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitLetRecExpr(ctx);
        // Convert the let into a lambda as an application.
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> letRecBindings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.letParameters().size(); i++) {
            MSSyntaxTree variable = this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(0));
            MSSyntaxTree expression = this.map.get(ctx.letParameters().get(i).expr(1));
            letRecBindings.add(new MSDeclarationNode(variable, expression));
        }
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSLetRecNode(letRecBindings, this.map.get(ctx.expr())));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitLambdaExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.LambdaExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitLambdaExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> lambdaParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ctx.lambdaParameters().expr() != null) {
            for (ParseTree pt : ctx.lambdaParameters().expr()) {
                lambdaParameters.add(this.map.get(pt));
            }
        }
        MSSyntaxTree lambdaBody = this.map.get(ctx.expr());
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSLambdaNode(lambdaParameters, lambdaBody));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitIfExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.IfExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitIfExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condPredicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condConsequentList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add the if statement.
        condPredicateList.add(this.map.get(ctx.expr(0)));

        // Add the if consequent.
        condConsequentList.add(this.map.get(ctx.expr(1)));

        // If there's an alternative add that.
        if (ctx.expr(2) != null) { condConsequentList.add(this.map.get(ctx.expr(2))); }
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSCondNode(condPredicateList, condConsequentList));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitCondExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.CondExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitCondExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condPredicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> condConsequentList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.condForm().size(); i++) {
            condPredicateList.add(this.map.get(ctx.condForm().get(i).expr(0)));
            condConsequentList.add(this.map.get(ctx.condForm().get(i).expr(1)));
        }

        // If the expr is non-null, there's an else statement.
        if (ctx.expr() != null) { condConsequentList.add(this.map.get(ctx.expr())); }
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSCondNode(condPredicateList, condConsequentList));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitSymbolExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.SymbolExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitSymbolExpr(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSSymbolNode(this.map.get(ctx.symbolDatum())));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitSymbolDatum(final MiniSchemeParser.SymbolDatumContext ctx) {
        super.exitSymbolDatum(ctx);
        // First, check to see if it's a list of expressions. If so, make it a MSListNode.
        if (ctx.variable() == null && ctx.constant() == null && ctx.PERIOD() == null) {
            MSSyntaxTree parentList;
            MSSyntaxTree currList = null;
            for (int i = ctx.symbolDatum().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                MSSyntaxTree rhsList = this.map.get(ctx.symbolDatum(i));
                currList = new MSListNode(rhsList, currList);
            }

            parentList = Optional.ofNullable(currList).orElse(MSListNode.EMPTY_LIST);
            this.map.put(ctx, parentList);
        } else if (ctx.PERIOD() != null) {
            // Test to see if we're using dot notation to make pairs.
            MSSyntaxTree lhsExpression = this.map.get(ctx.symbolDatum(0));
            MSSyntaxTree rhsExpression = this.map.get(ctx.symbolDatum(1));
            this.map.put(ctx, new MSListNode(lhsExpression, rhsExpression));
        } else {
            // Otherwise, just take the child that's there (either a variable or constant).
            this.map.put(ctx, this.map.get(ctx.getChild(0)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitQuasiSymbolExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.QuasiSymbolExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitQuasiSymbolExpr(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, this.map.get(ctx.quasiSymbolDatum()));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitQuasiSymbolDatum(MiniSchemeParser.QuasiSymbolDatumContext ctx) {
        super.exitQuasiSymbolDatum(ctx);
        // If it's the '(' datum* ')', construct it.
        if (ctx.variable() == null && ctx.constant() == null && ctx.symbolExpr() == null && ctx.applicationExpr() == null) {
            ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> elements = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ctx.quasiSymbolDatum().size(); i++) {
                elements.add(this.map.get(ctx.quasiSymbolDatum(i)));
            }
            this.map.put(ctx, new MSQuasiSymbolNode(elements));
        } else {
            // If it's just a normal symbol, then just take the child. We need to determine if it's
            // a "quasi at".
            if (ctx.COMMA() != null) {
                if (ctx.ATSIGN() != null) {
                    this.map.put(ctx, new MSSymbolNode(this.map.get(ctx.getChild(2)), true));
                } else {
                    this.map.put(ctx, this.map.get(ctx.getChild(1)));
                }
            } else {
                this.map.put(ctx, new MSSymbolNode(this.map.get(ctx.getChild(0))));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitSetExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.SetExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitSetExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> setData = new ArrayList<>();
        setData.add(this.map.get(ctx.variable()));
        setData.add(this.map.get(ctx.expr()));
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSSetNode(MiniSchemeParser.SET, setData));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitSetListExpr(final MiniSchemeParser.SetListExprContext ctx) {
        super.exitSetListExpr(ctx);
        ArrayList<MSSyntaxTree> setData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ParseTree pt : ctx.expr()) { setData.add(this.map.get(pt)); }
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSSetNode(((TerminalNode) ctx.getChild(1)).getSymbol().getType(), setData));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitConstant(final MiniSchemeParser.ConstantContext ctx) {
        super.exitConstant(ctx);
        int tokenType = ((TerminalNode) ctx.getChild(0)).getSymbol().getType();
        MSSyntaxTree constantNode;
        switch (tokenType) {
            case MiniSchemeParser.NUMBERLIT:
                constantNode = new MSNumberNode(ctx.getText());
                break;
            case MiniSchemeParser.BOOLLIT:
                constantNode = new MSBooleanNode(ctx.getText());
                break;
            case MiniSchemeParser.CHARLIT:
                constantNode = new MSCharacterNode(ctx.getText());
                break;
            case MiniSchemeParser.STRINGLIT:
                constantNode = new MSStringNode(ctx.getText());
                break;
            default:
                throw new MSInterpreterException("Invalid token type " + tokenType);
        }

        this.map.put(ctx, constantNode);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitVariable(final MiniSchemeParser.VariableContext ctx) {
        super.exitVariable(ctx);
        this.map.put(ctx, new MSVariableNode(ctx.ID().getText()));
    }

    public MSSyntaxTree getSyntaxTree() {
        return this.root;
    }
}
```